# Build urls based on select menu and button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a query and produced a drop down of the values. I want to create multiple buttons that will read the selected value from the drop down and use it for routing in the url.

```html
<select name="Item_1" id="ddval">
    {% for row in season %}
    <option value="{{ row[1] }} {{ row[0] }}">{{ row[1] }} {{ row[0] }}</option>
    {% endfor %}           
</select>
```

I want each button to read whatever the dropdown is on and then execute the script taking the specific value from the chosen option value

Button 1 to execute script 1

```
/script1/row[1]/row[0]
```

Button 2 to execute script 2

```
/script2/row[1]/row[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using javascript ( jquery ) for this task
first you get the value of the selected option

```
var val = $('#ddval:selected').val();
```

then you want to split the rows

```
var rows = val.split(" ");
```

then execute you application , to do that you need to listen to the button click event.

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
  location.replace("/script1/" + rows[0] + "/" + rows[1] );
  // you can do ajax , $.get .....
});


$("#button1").click(function(){
   location.replace("/script1/" + rows[0] + "/" + rows[1] );
   // you can do ajax , $.get .....
});
```